# WPF ContextMenu Binding ItemsSource on sub MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following `ContextMenu` in my `XAML`

```
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ExportContext">
        <MenuItem Header="Export Journey"
                  Command="{Binding ExportJourney}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Export..."
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTrip.Clips}">
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
```

The first `MenuItem` that binds to `ExportJourney` works as expected, and runs the `ICommand` from `HomeViewModel`.
However, the `SelectedTrip.Clips` binding doesn't seem to work at all.

Here is an extract from `HomeViewModel`, which is assigned as the window's `DataContext`

```
namespace ViewModel
{
    class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
    {
        private ICommand _exportJourney;
        private ObservableCollection<Journey> _journeyList = new ObservableCollection<Journey>();
        private Journey _selectedTrip;

        public IEnumerable<Journey> JourneyList
        {
           get { return _journeyList; }
        }

        public Journey SelectedTrip
        {
            get { return _selectedTrip; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedTrip != value)
                {
                    _selectedTrip = value;
                    _journeyList.Where(c => c.Selected == true).ToList().ForEach(a => a.Selected = false);
                    _journeyList.Where(c => c.StartTime == value.StartTime).ToList().ForEach(a => a.Selected = true);
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTrip");
                }
            }
        }

        public ICommand ExportJourney
        {
            get
            {
                if (_exportJourney == null)
                {
                    _exportJourney = new RelayCommand(
                        p => ExtractJourney(),
                        p => SelectedTrip != null);
                }

                return _exportJourney;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Journey` class contains a property `Clips`, which is a `List<Clip>`. The `Clip` class then contains the string property of `Name` which is to be displayed.

`JourneyList` is displayed in a `DataGrid` and as a row is selected the `Journey` is set as the `SelectedTrip`

I do not understand why the Binding to `ExportJourney` `ICommand` works perfectly, but nothing appears under the Export... header.
The only thing I can think of, is that `SelectedJourney` is null at the time of loading?

If, for testing purposes, I bound to `JourneyList` rather than `SelectedTrip.Clips` the binding works and I get a submenu (albeit, with no names, but the places are there!)

Not really sure about what to do to debug this? Any advice on debugging bindings, or suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong, are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question in less than 10 minutes, yet it took me a week of Googling to get to posting it on here. I hate the way the world works sometimes!

**Answer:**
`ItemsSource` on a `ContextMenu` cannot be of type `list`.

I adjusted my `Journey` class so that the public `Clip` property was a `IEnumerable<Clip>` (private `Clip` property became an `ObservableCollection<Clip>`), rather than `List<Clip>`